# __str__ not showing String

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I'm writing a Django application and upon login I want it to show the first and last names of the user. This is my model -

```
class Admins(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user.is_admin = True
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

When I call the ***str*** function in my views.py it returns -
"function Admins.**str** at 0x00000135A3083708"

Here is my view -

```
def AdminLandingPage(request):
    name = Admins.__str__
    print(name) #using this part to display above mentioned error
    return render(request,'form1/adminlanding.html',{'USTYPE':"ADMIN","FN":name})
```

When I checked my HTML file, it showed up blank. It was supposed to display the first and last name. Instead, neither the string (name) nor the context is able to show this.

Here is my HTML file -

```
<body>
<p>

{{FN}}
</p>
```

Comment: You don't need to call `str(name)` or `name.__str__()` to get the name. Just put the variable name in `print()` or in your HTML code and Python will automatically invoke that function.

Comment: @MohammedFarahmand I tried that as well, it did not work, which is why I used str(name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all in order to get a result of the function, you would need to run `__str__()` (you are missing the `()`).

Second:

Currently your `name` variable is just the `Admins`-Model definition, not an instance.

In order to get the current users name you need to get the model instance for it, like:

```py
def AdminLandingPage(request):
    user = request.user
    admin = user.admins  # get your Admins-instance with reverse-relation from User-object
    name = str(admin)
    print(name)  # will print aus the result of Admins.__str__() for the given instance
    return render(request, 'form1/adminlanding.html', {'USTYPE': 'ADMIN', 'FN': name})
```

Comment: Firstly, when I tried .__str__() it said it was missing the 'self' argument. Secondly, I tried what you did and it's still printing - <class 'P.models.User'> instead of the String.

Comment: If you do `Admins.__str__()` it won't work, yes. That's because you need to have an instance of that object, `Admins` itself is just the definition of the model. From your second case it seems like you returned the user-model to the view, not the related `user.admins`-class or the returned string of it.

Comment: What exactly should I do to return the user.admins class String?

Comment: The property `admins` on `User` is your `Admins`-model since you referenced it with a [OneToOneRelation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships). With `request.user` you are receiving the Django `User`-model for the currently active user. And if you do `request.user.admins` you got your `Admins` instance where you can call your string-method.